# Definition of Base-point

Tags: algebraic-geometry, definition

Consider the family of curves defined by $f(x,y)=g(x)+h(y)+a$, where $a$ is a free parameter. Now, it states that the family of curves intersect at $\infty$ and that $\infty$ is a base-point of these family of curves. What is the definition/meaning of base-point in this context?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $f_a(x,y)=g(x)+h(y)+a=\sum_{i=0}^N  b_ix^i+  \sum_{j=0}^n  c_jx^j +a $ with, say, $N\geq n$ and $b_N\neq 0$ .
Homogeneizing we get $F_a(x,y,z)=\sum_{i=0}^N  b_ix^iz^{N-i}+  \sum_{j=0}^n  c_jx^jz^{N-j} +az^N$.

The points at infinity of the curve $C_a=V(F_a)$ obtained by setting $F_a(x,y,z)=0$ are the points $\infty_k=(\xi_k:\eta_k:0)$ where the  $(\xi_k:\eta_k)$ are the zeros of the equation $b_Nx^N+c_Ny^N=0$ (with the obvious convention that $c_N=0$ if $n\lt N$).

Have you noticed that the $\infty_k=(\xi_k:\eta_k:0)$ do **not** depend on $a$ ?
This means that **all** the curves $C_a=V(F_a)$ go through these infinity  points  $\infty_k$ and this is the meaning of the $\infty_k$'s being base points of the family (=linear system= pencil) of curves $(C_a)_a$ .

Comment: Thanks. Let me see if I understand the definition. Consider the following Weiestrass equation: $y^2=4x^3-x+a$. Homogeneizing gives $y^2 z=4x^3-x z^2+az^3$. When $z=0$ we get $0=4x^3$. Thus, $x=0$ and $y$ is free. So, $\infty_k=(0:\eta_k:0)$. Is this correct?

Comment: Dear Radz:  yes, you are correct   but beware that there is only **one** base point at infinity for your family, namely $\infty=(0:1:0)$.

Comment: Dear Georges Elencwajg: Could you please explain why that is so or maybe recommend a book? Thanks.

Comment: Dear Radz, if $y^2z=4x^3−xz^2+az^3$ and $z=0$ you get $4x^3=0$, so that $x=0$ too.Hence for any value of $a$ the only point at infinity is indeed $(0:1:0)$ .

Answer (score 1):

Given a linear system and any point $x ∈ X$, $X$ a $k$-scheme, on which all elements of the linear system $V$ vanish, we say that $x$ is a base-point of $V$. See [here](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3ahttp://math.stanford.edu/~vakil/0708-216/216class32.pdf).

Comment: If possible, could you please explain this using a simple example? Thanks.